# At how many points will $\lfloor(sin x + cos x )\rfloor$ be discontinuous in the interval [0,2$\pi$]

Tags: functions, trigonometry

At how  many points will $\lfloor(sin x + cos x )\rfloor$ be discontinuous in the interval [0,2$\pi$] ? How should the graph be ?

Comment: Probably easier to analyze if you rewrite $\sin x + \cos x$ as a single trig function:
$$\sin x + \cos x = \sqrt{2} \left( {1 \over \sqrt 2} \sin x + {1 \over \sqrt 2} \cos x \right) = \sqrt 2 \sin\left( x + { \pi \over 4 } \right) $$

So then the question becomes: when is $\sin\left( x + { \pi \over 4 } \right)$ in the intervals $[0,1/\sqrt{2}), [1/\sqrt{2},1], ...$

Comment: Graph $\sin(x) + \cos(x)$ and then apply the floor function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guess you can graph it.  You might need to think carefully about the endpoints, though - or at any point where we just touch an integer value.

[image]